# Menu issue with switch. When i input my choice, it works for all of mu switches

Tags: java, menu, switch-statement, case

Its hard to explain, but basically if i press 3 it works for all of my case parts (switches). How do i make Value be new every time. If i for example press 3, then it prints this:

Pasirinkite objekta ir jo metoda
-1 Buyer
-2 Item
-3 Shop
Shop. Pasirinkite metoda
1 Name
2 Email
3 Company Code
4 Address
5 Delivery Price
Comapny code: 
Invalis selection

```
public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int Value = 0;



    System.out.println("***************************************Menu***************************************");
    System.out.println("1 - jei norite atspauzdinti programje sukurtu objektu sarasus");
    System.out.println("2 - jei norite sukurti naujus objektus, ju duomenis ivedant is klavieturos");
    System.out.println("3 - jei norite iskviesti objektu metodus");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {
       Value = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
    }



    switch (Value) {
    case 1: {
        System.out.println("1 Selected");
        break;
    }
    case 2: 
        System.out.println("2 Selected");
        break;


    case 3: 
        System.out.println("Pasirinkite objekta ir jo metoda");
        System.out.println("-1 Buyer");
        System.out.println("-2 Item");
        System.out.println("-3 Shop");
        if (Value == 3) {
        switch(Value) {


        case 1: 
            System.out.println("Buyer. Pasirinkite metoda");
            System.out.println("1 Email");
            System.out.println("2 Phone Number");
            switch(Value) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Email: ");// + getEmail());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Phone number: ");// + getPhoneNumber());
                break;
            }

            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Item. Pasirinkite metoda");
            System.out.println("1 Name");
            System.out.println("2 Price");
            System.out.println("3 Warranty");
            System.out.println("4 Extra Warrantys");
            //value4 = input.next();
            switch(Value) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Name: ");// + getName());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Price: ");// + getPrice());
                break;
            case 3: 
                System.out.println("Warranty: ");// + getWarranty());
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Extra warranty: ");// + getExtraWarranty());
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 3: 
            System.out.println("Shop. Pasirinkite metoda");
            System.out.println("1 Name");
            System.out.println("2 Email");
            System.out.println("3 Company Code");
            System.out.println("4 Address");
            System.out.println("5 Delivery Price");
            switch(Value) {
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Name: ");// + getName());
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Email: ");// + getEmail());
                break;
            case 3: 
                System.out.println("Comapny code: ");// + s.getCompanyCode());
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Address: ");// + getAddress());
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Delivery price: ");// + getDeliveryPrice());
                break;
            }

        break;
        }
        }
    default: System.out.println("Invalis selection");
    break;

}
```

}
}

Comment: What do you want to do? Your logic is a bit messy. Look at your switch-in-switch-in-switch: `switch (Value) { ... case 3: ... if (Value == 3) { ... switch  (Value) { ... case 3: ...`, what is the expected result of all this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the problem, but I think you want to read a new value between each switch. So you should add lines here to read from the keyboard again

```
case 3: 
    System.out.println("Pasirinkite objekta ir jo metoda");
    System.out.println("-1 Buyer");
    System.out.println("-2 Item");
    System.out.println("-3 Shop");

    try {
        Value = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
       ioe.printStackTrace();
    }


    if (Value == 3) {
        ....
```

If I were you, I would rearrange the code to avoid using nested switches and using more methods. It is really hard to read